# Help with breaking SSL pinning of this app

Tags: tls, android, reverse-engineering

I need help removing SSL pinning of [this](https://filebin.net/vaz7k8a7sy1xqdq6/pcoptimum.apk) *original* Android app. I've tried different techniques like hooking the app with Objection, re-pinning with Frida, using the SSLUnpinning app from the Xposed repo, etc. but nothing seemed to work, this is a hard app and I'm really having a hard time here.

My problem is I don't know reverse engineering that well and it just makes things more difficult for me. However, I've found something inside the code, I don't know if this is what's handling the SSL pinning or not but this was the closest thing I could find. Here's the piece of code:

```
 private static SchemeRegistry a(boolean paramBoolean, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
    if (paramBoolean) {
      Log.d("AsyncHttpClient", "Beware! Using the fix is insecure, as it doesn't verify SSL certificates.");
    }
    int i = paramInt1;
    if (paramInt1 < 1)
    {
      i = 80;
      Log.d("AsyncHttpClient", "Invalid HTTP port number specified, defaulting to 80");
    }
    paramInt1 = paramInt2;
    if (paramInt2 < 1)
    {
      paramInt1 = 443;
      Log.d("AsyncHttpClient", "Invalid HTTPS port number specified, defaulting to 443");
    }
    if (paramBoolean) {}
    for (SSLSocketFactory localSSLSocketFactory = d.b();; localSSLSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
    {
      SchemeRegistry localSchemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
      localSchemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), i));
      localSchemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", localSSLSocketFactory, paramInt1));
      return localSchemeRegistry;
    }
  }
```

Couldn't figure it out myself so I thought why not ask the pros. Please help, really trying to understand this stuff. Will make my life a whole lot easier.